# AngularJS - Unable to remove added css class that was added on click

Tags: css, angularjs, rotatetransform

I'm creating a simple drop down menu with an animated chevron whenever the user clicks on it. I managed to attach the rotation class to the element on click, but I cannot remove it when the user clicks elsewhere. I guess I need to detect clicks on the dom and act accordingly. I read [this](http://www.markschabacker.com/blog/2014/12/26/angular-any-other-click/) blog, but having troubles implementing that code. Is there a simpler method rotating the chevron back?

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6w852xh5/1/).

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <span class="dropdown dropDownSettings" ng-click="rotate = !rotate">
            <i class="fa fa-chevron-down draftDetails" id="editDropDown" data-toggle="dropdown" ng-class="{'rotate180' : rotate}"></i>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="editDropDown">
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">Edit</a></li>
                <li role="presentation"><a role="menuitem" tabindex="-1" href="">Delete</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.rotate = false;
});
```

CSS:

```
.dropDownSettings {
  margin-left: 100px;
  margin-top: 100px;
  cursor: pointer;
}


/*rotate 180*/

.rotate180 {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}

.draftDetails {
  -webkit-transition: all .3s;
  -moz-transition: all .3s;
  -ms-transition: all .3s;
  transition: all .3s;
}
```

Comment: you might want to look at $broadcast and $on

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this much more easily using CSS. Just apply the transform when the dropdown has the `open` class.

```
.dropDownSettings.open .draftDetails  {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
  transform: rotate(180deg);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/h9ga73fb/

Answer (score 0):

`onblur` is the event that triggers when an element loses focus, so you could use that to determine when a user 'clicks elsewhere'.

It seems odd that you want the rotate class to apply when the element is clicked on, and be removed when they click elsewhere, surely it should depend on the expanded / collapsed state of the dropdown instead? There is a library for the bootstrap plugins in angular: https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/